# Location of webroot (for css file) in Perfect app

Tags: html, css, swift, xcode, perfect

I've cloned the PerfectTemplate project and am using it to serve up html as follows…

```
import PerfectHTTP
import PerfectHTTPServer

var routes = Routes()

routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/test") { request, response in
    response.addHeader(.contentType, value: "text/html")
    response.setBody(string: """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>Test!</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="Welcome">Hello</div>
            </body>
        </html>
        """)
    response.completed()
}

routes.add(method: .get, 
              uri: "/**", 
          handler: StaticFileHandler(documentRoot: "./webroot", allowResponseFilters: true).handleRequest)

try HTTPServer.launch(name: "localhost", 
                      port: 8181, 
                    routes: routes, 
           responseFilters: [(PerfectHTTPServer.HTTPFilter.contentCompression(data: [:]), HTTPFilterPriority.high)])
```

I'm compiling and running with Xcode, and `http://localhost:8181/test` is returning the html as expected.

The problem is the location of the external css file. As far as I can tell this should be in a folder called `webroot`, but where should that folder be when running locally?

For reference, I'm coming at this as an iOS dev, so my knowledge of web development and server config is limited.

---

*Update*

Per a suggestion on the Perfect Slack group, I added the css file to the project folder (the same folder as `Package.swift`), and set the **Working Directory** of the scheme `$(PROJECT_DIR)` - but I’m getting a 404 trying to load `http://localhost:8181/style.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the Perfect Slack group, I found a solution. The missing piece for me was the `webroot` folder. I'd assumed this was some kind of alias, but it turns out that you do need to create an actual folder called `webroot`. So…

1. Set the **Working Directory** of the scheme to `$(PROJECT_DIR)`
2. In the project folder, create a folder named `webroot` and add the css file to that folder. It should look like this…

[image]

I'm sure all the seasoned web devs are laughing at me right now!